# Unbiased coin toss of n coins with different success values for each coin

Tags: probability

Lets say we have n coins and probability of Coin i to fall heads is f(i) .
Find the probability of getting even number of heads when all the n coins are tossed.

f(i) = 1 / (2i + 3)

Here n is large, of the order of 1e5, so efficient approach is required.

I tried to analyse the brute force case but that would be too much i.e. If I calculate for 2 success, 4, 6..., it might take years to run.

Then I thought of applying Linearity of Expectation somehow but couldn't come up with anything which could help.
​​

Comment: Is an approximation good enough? I suspect the result is going to be very close to 1/2. For an exact result, think about a Markov chain on 2 states, named odd and even. If coin i = heads, then there is a transition from odd to even or from even to odd. If coin i = tails, you stay in the same state. Each coin toss gives one transition matrix and the n = 1e5 steps transition matrix is just the product of m(1) . m(2) . m(3) ... m(1e5). The transition probabilities are given by the function f which you mentioned. You can easily find that product; it is just the product of 2x2 transition matrices.

Comment: @RobertDodier indeed, pretty close to .5, though I used recursion (which is another way to get Markov chain going)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be simple recursion, isn't?

Let's p(k) = 1/(2*k+3), q(k) = 1 - p(k), V(k) is probability to have even tosses after k.

Let's consider last throw

```
V(n) = q(n)*V(n-1) + p(n)*(1-V(n-1)) = (q(n)-p(n))*V(n-1) + p(n)
V(0) = 1
```

C++ code

```
#include <iostream>

inline double p(int k) {
    return 1.0/(2.0*k + 3.0);
}

inline double q(int k) {
    return 1.0 - p(k);
}

double V(int k) {
    if (k == 0)
        return 1.0;

    return (q(k) - p(k))*V(k-1) + p(k);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << V(10000) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

V(10000) is indeed pretty close to .5

```
V(10000) = 0.500075
```